# Append string to record

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, oracle11g

**Environement** : Oracle 11gR2  , ASP .Net, VB

**Aim**: need to append text string to an existing record.

**Problem**: When using the following

```
    strSQL += "Update table_name SET "
    strSQL += " JOB = '" & Trim(Me.txtjob.Text) & "',"
    strSQL += " NAME = '" & Trim(Me.txtname.Text) & "',"
    strSQL += " REMARK = REMARK ||  '  " & Trim(Me.txtremark.Text) & "'"
```

It appends the already existing data along with the new data to the new data.
Example:

> Contents before SQL Execution: ABC
>   Contents to append: DEF
>   Result after execution : ABCABCDEF
>   expected result: ABCDEF

I tried to use a few permutations to get the right result but to no avail.
Any suggestions/resolution will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you updating the field 3 times in one statement?  And it that your _actual_ query?  I'd expect you to get `ABCDEF` as well.

Comment: Hi guys, appreciate your swift reply. This is an Intranet site, and I am not updating the field 3 times, its 3 different fields, overlooked doing field1.name, field2.name... My bad.

Comment: Without the proper field names, we cannot help you. You call them `Field.name` in the query, but you don't mention that name outside the query (instead you mention `Contents`.) Without knowing which field is which, we cannot assist.

Comment: @EBrown there you go updated the question, hope that explains the problem better.

Comment: What is `Contents`? You still do not indicate what it represents. Which of those fields is the `Contents` before and to append representing? Something tells me we'll need the entire `save` code to troubleshoot.

Comment: This code will not work at all, see the space between `Me.` and `txtremark.Text`

Comment: @EBrown hi, the field is just holding random text about a job(aka activity). It is not doing anything clever, i just need to keep adding to the existing data in the record, but whenever i am using the code above, it keeps duplicating the existing data and then adds the new info, let me know where do you want me to dump the function for you to have a look at

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand or not...what ***column*** is it affecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems that this was a rather straight forward solution which i ended up over complicating.

IN my case:

I was reading the record and displaying it in a text box.

What i ended up doing was :

just update the entire contents of the text box again to the record.
Thus overwriting the already existing contents along with the modified contents of the textbox.

strSQL += " DOC_LOCATION = '" & System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Trim(Me.txtremark.Text)) & (" Last Edit: ") & temp & "  " & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") & "'"

Since this was a rather simple application, this solution worked for me.